# Sum of the cells around a single cell in a matrix with python

Tags: python, matrix, sum

I have two matrices: in "matrix" there are 0 and 1. In "matrix_2" I would like to sum the cells around the single cell.
For example:

```
matrix =
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

And

```
matrix_2 =
[[0 0 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 0]
[2 4 4 0 6 6 0 3 0 0]
[0 0 6 8 8 7 0 3 0 0]
[0 0 4 7 7 6 4 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

In this case, matrix_2 computes the sum of the cell and the cells immediately around.

```
matrix_2 = np.zeros((y_segment, x_segment), dtype=int)
for y_matrix in xrange(0, y_segment, 1):
    for x_matrix in xrange(0, x_segment, 1):
        if matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] != 0:
            if 0 < x_matrix < x_segment - 1 and 0 < y_matrix < y_segment - 1:
                # print "y_matrix: " + str(y_matrix) + ", x_matrix: " + str(x_matrix)
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix-1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix-1][x_matrix-1] + matrix[y_matrix-1][x_matrix+1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix-1] + matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix+1] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix-1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix+1]
            if x_matrix == 0 and y_matrix == 0:  # 1
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix+1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix+1] + matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix]
            if x_matrix == 0 and y_matrix == y_segment-1:  # 10
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix + 1] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix + 1]
            if x_matrix == x_segment-1 and y_matrix == y_segment-1:  # 12
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix - 1]
            if x_matrix == x_segment-1 and y_matrix == 0:  # 3
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix-1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix]
            if x_matrix == 0 and y_matrix != 0 and y_matrix != y_segment-1:
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix-1][x_matrix] + \
                                               matrix[y_matrix-1][x_matrix+1] + matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix] + \
                                               matrix[y_matrix+1][x_matrix+1] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix+1]
            if x_matrix == x_segment-1 and y_matrix != 0 and y_matrix != y_segment-1:
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix - 1]
            if y_matrix == 0 and x_matrix != 0 and x_matrix != x_segment-1:
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix + 1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix + 1] + matrix[y_matrix + 1][x_matrix - 1]
            if y_matrix == y_segment-1 and x_matrix != 0 and x_matrix != x_segment-1:
                matrix_2[y_matrix][x_matrix] = matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix] + matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix + 1] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix][x_matrix - 1] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix] + \
                                           matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix + 1] + matrix[y_matrix - 1][x_matrix - 1]
```

But know I would like to compute the sum of the 9x9 cells around my cell.
Is there a function for that? Because for sure my code is not well written and it will be very long. Thank you.

Comment: You say you want to calculate the sum of the 10x10 cells too, but doesn't this only make sense for odd kernel sizes? Else you end up with an asymmetric kernel

Comment: @MaartenFabré Oops sorry, I edit for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve)

## kernel

```
size=3
kernel = np.ones((size,size))
```

> ```
> array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
>        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
>        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
> ```

## calculation

```
result = signal.convolve(matrix, kernel, method='direct').astype(int)
```

> ```
> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0],
>         [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0],
>         [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2, 0, 0],
>         [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 0, 0],
>         [0, 0, 2, 4, 7, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0],
>         [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
> ```

## trimming

This adds the outer layers too, so you need to trim these

```
result_trimmed = result[(size-1)//2:-(size-1)//2,(size-1)//2:-(size-1)//2]
```

> ```
> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0],
>        [2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 3, 1, 0],
>        [2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2, 0],
>        [2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 0],
>        [0, 2, 4, 7, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0],
>        [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0]])
> ```

## Pure python

This does the same as the `scipy` alternative

```
from itertools import product
def convolution(matrix, size):
    if size % 2 != 1:
        ValueError('`size` must be an odd integer')
    h, w = (len(matrix), max(len(row) for row in matrix), )
#     print(w, h)
    result = [[0] * w for _ in range(h)]
    for x, y in product(range(w), range(h)):
#         print(x, y)
        y_min, y_max = max(0, y - size // 2), min(h, y + size // 2 + 1)
        x_min, x_max = max(0, x - size // 2), min(w, x + size // 2 + 1)
#         print(matrix[y][x], x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max)
        rows = matrix[y_min: y_max]
        result[y][x] = sum(sum(row[x_min: x_max]) for row in rows)
    return result
```

## OP's `matrix2`

If that is the result the OP expects, this can be achieved by

### numpy method:

assuming `matrix` is the `np.array` form of the initial matrix

```
np.where(matrix != 0, result_trimmed, 0)
```

> ```
> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0],
>        [2, 4, 4, 0, 6, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 6, 8, 8, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 4, 7, 7, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
> ```

### native python

Add 2 lines in the inner loop:

```
...
    for x, y in product(range(w), range(h)):
        if matrix[y][x] == 0:
            continue
...
```

Comment: This produces the output I would expect after reading the OP's description. I think it needs clarification, why his expected output `matrix2` differs

Comment: @MrT. The OP's `matrix2` code only gives the values where there is a point in the original matrix. If that is what (s)he wants, this can be added too

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but for 
cell 
`matrix[r][c]`
we're adding following values

```
r-1,c-1
r-1,c
r-1,c+1
r,c-1
r,c
r,c+1
r+1,c-1
r+1,c
r+1,c+1
```

I have written following code please check.

```
def get_sum_of_cells_around(matrix,num_rows,num_cols):

    def valid(r,c):
        if r<0 or r>=num_rows or c<0 or c>=num_cols:
            return False
        return True


    result = []
    for r in range(0,num_rows):
        row = []
        for c in range(0,num_cols):
            value = 0
            for i in range(-1,2):
                for j in range(-1,2):
                    if valid(r+i,c+j):
                       value+=matrix[r+i][c+j]
            row.append(value)
        result.append(row)
    return result
```